# keycode issues in chrome for android mobile

Tags: android, google-chrome, mobile

keycode returns 0 on keydown. I can see from all the forum posts i've read this this has been like this for years. Is there an alternative way to identify what key was pressed on keydown?

Comment: After further investigation and google search I believe I may need to use either edittext or beforeinput to identify what key was pressed on the android soft keyboard. Does anyone have examples of either of these approaches that they can point me to?